# Apache Tomcat Eclipse Java IDE

Tags: java, apache, eclipse, tomcat, ide

Olá, estou tendo um problema com a inicialização do meu servidor TomCat, primeiro ele acusou aquele problema de "Localhost already in use", após pesquisar sobre eu mudei as portas e ele subiu o server por um tempo determinado, e logo voltou a aparecer essa mensagem porém com as portas novas que eu tinha setado, e nisso ele já não funciona mais nenhuma, tentei já encerrar os processos pelo cmd que se referem as mesmas portas e nada.. Alguém sabe se dentro da IDE tem algo pra encerrar as portas ou algo assim?

Desde já, agradeço.

Answer (score 0):

Boa Tarde,

Geralmente isso acontece quando você está rodando mais de uma instancia do programa ao mesmo tempo.

Por exemplo: Você subiu uma aplicação, efetuou teste e caiu em uma Exception mas você não pausou o servidor, se você for rodar a aplicação novamente, vai dar esse erro.

Um bom teste a se fazer é: Se você estiver rodando no windows, ao dar esse erro, inicia o gerenciador de tarefas e verifica se tem um processo javaw rodando, se tiver, finaliza ele "na mão" mesmo e volte a executar seu programa.

Uma boa prática é sempre parar o servidor de aplicação dentro do eclipse entre esses testes e validações.

A opção dos servidores fica no tab Servers, se não aparecer pra você procure por Servers no Quick Access.

[image: Tab Servers]

No canto superior direito tem as opções de entrar no modo debug, Iniciar e Pausar (onde ele desce as portas).

Processo do javaw em execução
[image: Processo javaw]

Fui subir uma aplicação que usa a mesma porta tomei o erro:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Parei o servidor pelo eclipse e funcionou.

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta. Porém, quando entro no gerenciador de tarefas, não tem nenhum javaw.exe, apenas o eclipse rodando e nada mais, por isso acredito que seja problemas com as portas.